# Variables Execution in bash

Tags: command-line

I m trying to work some bash scripts on my own.

Let's say I'd like add "hi" at the beginning of lines such as;

```
a="find . -type f"

$ for i in $a;do echo hi $i; done
```

but output is:

```
hi find
hi .
hi -type
hi f
```

I'd like to put every beginning of variable execution as file output, which is here a, "hi" how can i do that?

EDIT: i want to add hi to very fron of "a" variables output, but this script adding hi every line of a..

EDIT: for type -f to -type f, thanks @Terrance

may output be;

```
hi ./me
hi ./you
```

sorry for unclear question i hope may edit work...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're talking about, but possibly you want to quote your variables `for i in "$a"; do echo hi "$i"; done` (the first is critical here, the second advisable)

Comment: You have added `hi` inside the loop, so it will be printed everytime the loop is executed. write `echo hi` outside the loop.

Comment: please [edit] your question, and add the *expected output*. (i.e. how would you like to see the output of your script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop treats the `$a` as a string and will not execute it.

Use `$(command)` when you need to execute something inside another command.

So what you would do in your case is (please don't do that, but follow the hint below):

```
for i in $($a); do echo hi $i; done
```

Additional Hint: Avoid using a for loop with find output, as you will run into issues when your file names contain spaces.

In your case the following will work:

```
a="find . -type f"
while IFS= read -r i; do
    echo "hi $i"
done < <($a)
```

`<(command)` creates a temporary file of the command output.)

Comment: nowly, tried  this; for i in `$a`;do echo hi $i; done , i got what i want but why do i need to put `` ?

Comment: `\`...\`` is more or less the "same" as `$(...)`. But I did not write that...